# Nullset regarding Probability distribution, Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question regarding a proof:

Let $(χ,\mathcal F,P_ϑ:ϑ∈Θ)$ be a statistical model, where $χ$ is the set of possible observations, $\mathcal F$ a $σ$-algebra and $(P_ϑ:ϑ∈Θ)$ is a parameterized set of probability distributions on $χ$.

As a condition, we have, that $P_ϑ$ has a positive probability density function regarding the lebesgue measure $μ$ on $χ$.

Now the proof has already shown, that a event named $N_ϑ$ is a nullset regarding $P_ϑ$. So we have $P_ϑ(N_ϑ)=0$

Now the proof says, that because of the fact $P_ϑ$ has a positive probability density function regarding the lebesgue measure $μ$ on $χ$, this implies $μ(N_ϑ)=0$.

But why? In which way are $P_ϑ$ and $μ$ connected. $P_ϑ(N_ϑ)=0\overset{\text{?}}{\implies}μ(N_ϑ)=0$, because of the positive probability density function regarding the lebesgue measure $μ$ on $χ$?

Could someone explain this to me? Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

greets Raffael-M

Comment: Indeed, if $Q$ have an everywhere positive PDF with respect to $\mu$ then $Q(N)=0$ if and only if $\mu(N)=0$. (Then $Q$ and $\mu$ are said to be equivalent.)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, for a measure 
$$Q(A)=\int_A fd\mu$$
where $f$ is strictly positive function, 
$$\mu(A)>0 \implies Q(A)>0.$$
The proof, which can be found in the beginning of every measure theory textbook, goes something like this: you observe that 
$$A_n=\{x \in A \mid f(x) \geq 1/n\} \uparrow A$$
and therefore $\mu(A_n) \to \mu(A)$. If $\mu(A)>0$, then $\mu(A_k)>0$ for some $k$, and 
$$Q(A)=\int_A fd\mu \geq \int _A \frac{1}{k}\chi_{B_k}d\mu=\frac{\mu(B_k)}{k}>0.$$